# maven-metadata.xml file is not updating correctly in nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype, aether, maven-metadata

I have uploaded different versions of an artifact to nexus repository by programmatically using aether API . I

But when I deleted an artifact from nexus remote repository, the maven-metadata.xml file is not updated correctly. The release version still points to the artifact that I have deleted.

Is there any way I can update the metadata file?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the metadata on the repository manually in the UI, via a scheduled task or via the REST API. In general you have to keep in mind that the metadata files have to be managed by the client (e.g. Maven itself or your code..), and Nexus just offers features to fix the metadata as a help since some clients don't maintain the metadata correctly.

E.g. in the UI. Log in as administrator, go to Repositories, select the repo in the list, right click and press 'Rebuild metadata'

If you want to do it only for a part of the repo you can go to the Browse Storage tab, drill down to the folder you want to update and do the same right click action.

Comment: You said metadata files have to be managed by the client. How maven is doing this (Any link or doc for this?). How can I implement a client code for this??

Comment: Maven downloads the file before any deployments, modifies it and uploads it again. Just see the log of any mvn deploy run.